# Error loading Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

[image]

[image]

I am trying to run an applet in my browser but keep getting an error that says "Application Blocked. Your security settings have blocked a local application from running". I've went into the Java Control Panel and tried to change the settings but was unable to do so. I don't know if this will help but here is the html element I am using:

```html
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="200" height="400">
    <param name="code" value="applet.PieChart">
    <param name="archive" value="James_Sole_-_PRG-421_Week_4_Assignment.jar">
        Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox, couldn't get it to run on Chrome

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Java VM setting as below:

```
Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and search for Configure Java)
Click on the Security tab
Click on the Edit Site List button
Click Add in the Exception Site List window
Click in the empty field under the Location field to enter the URL
```

Comment: I am trying to allow a local file (file:///C:/Users/Jimmy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/James%20Sole%20-%20PRG-421%20Week%204%20Assignment/src/applet/applet.html)

Comment: I added the local file to the security exceptions in the java control panel but it is still giving me the general exception security settings have blocked a local application from running.

Comment: Hm. what is that applet from? Did you write it?

Comment: <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="200" height="400">
    <param name="code" value="applet.PieChart">
    <param name="archive" value="James_Sole_-_PRG-421_Week_4_Assignment.jar">
        Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>

Comment: Try to restart your browser after changing Java security setting.